# Echo WordPress post featured image URL inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am trying to echo WordPress post featured image URL inside JS file.

Below code will get the URL of wordpress post featured image:

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?><img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```

I have embedded the above code inside the below JS file.

```
var fapDom = '<div id="fap-wrapper" class="'+(options.wrapperPosition == 'top' ? 'fap-wrapper-top' : 'fap-wrapper-bottom')+' mjv-playlist-bg" style="'+options.wrapperPosition+': 0; height: '+totalHeight+'px;"><?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?><img src="<?php echo $url ?>" /><div id="fap-main" style="color:'+options.mainColor+';"><div id="fap-wrapper-switcher" style="background: '+options.wrapperColor+'; border-color: '+options.strokeColor+'" class="fap-'+options.wrapperPosition+'"></div><p id="fap-init-text">Creating...</p></div></div>';
```

But this is not working. PHP code not working inside the JS file, so is it possible to fetch the WordPress post featured image URL which is compatible to insert in the place of PHP code.

Comment: Maybe I am too unexperienced with word press, but could you explain, why you do not process the javascript text input on the server and by php (which would evaluate the snippet) and before sending the then valid javascript with the resulting URL ot the clients browser? The one line code display does it also not make easy to read and check for validity (syntax). So please explain a bit more about what you mean by "fetch the WordPress post featured image URL". Thanks

Comment: @Dilettant - in the javascript code, the img tag src have to get the URL of wordpress post featured image. I don't know how to do this in JS